# Endless run time for-loop in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, time, runtime

I have recently created this code and I am struggling with my run time for my for-loops. If I try to run this code, R is seems to take forever and I am not sure where the mistake is:

```
Graph <- rbind(c(0,0.8,0,0.2,0.1),
          c(0,0,0.7,0.6,0.1),
          c(0,0,0,0,0.9),
          c(0,0,0,0,0.2),
          c(0,0,0,0,0))
AmountNodes<-5
Method<-"unweighted"
InfectedNodes<-c(1)

## Function Amount Excluded
SIR_algorithm<-function(Graph, AmountNodes, Method){
ResultMatrix <- rep(0, AmountNodes)
as.data.frame(ResultMatrix)
if (strcmp(Method,"unweighted")){
Graph <- sign(Graph)}
for (i in 1:AmountNodes){
InfectedNodes <- rep(AmountNodes, 0)
ExcludedNodes <- rep(AmountNodes, 0)
InfectedNodes <-c(1)} # Initial Infection, k=Columns, j=Rows

while(sum(InfectedNodes) > 0){
  InfectedNodes_Reflection <- InfectedNodes
  for (j in 1:nrow(Graph)){
    if (Graph[j] == 1){
      for (k in 1:ncol(Graph)){
        if ((Graph[k,j] > 0 && (InfectedNodes[k][1]) == 0 && (ExcludedNodes[k][1]) == 0)){ 
          RandomValue <- runif(1, max=1, min=0) 
          if (RandomValue < (Graph[k,j])){
            InfectedNodes_Reflection[k] <- k == 1
          } #End If-Function
        } #End If-Function
      } #End For-Function k
    } #End If-Function
  }} #End For-Function j

  for (j in 1:AmountNodes){ 
    if (InfectedNodes[j] == 1){
      InfectedNodes[j] <- c(0)
      InfectedNodes_Reflection[j] <- c(0)
      ExcludedNodes[j] <- c(1)}} #End If-Function and for-function

  InfectedNodes <- InfectedNodes_Reflection
  ResultMatrix[i] <- ExcludedNodes
  length(ResultMatrix) #check length for ResultMatrix
  length(ExcludedNodes) #check length for ExcludedNodes
} #End While-Function
#End For-Function i
AmountExcluded <- sum(ResultMatrix)/AmountNodes
#Damage Values<- ResultMatrix * Damage Potential
}  #End Function_total

SIR_algorithm(Graph=Graph,AmountNodes=5,Method="unweighted")
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: The mistake is that you are writing R code in C style. R shines if you utilize its vectorization.

Comment: (a) Can you describe in words what your code is doing? It is very difficult to debug "code" without context. Comments like `#End if function` aren't actually very helpful because they explain nothing that isn't self-evident from the code, whereas comments like `#Random value determines if cell becomes infected` can help by explaining goals of the code...

Comment: (b) How have you tried to isolate the problem? Have you tried adding 
 `print`statements in the loop counters so you can tell how far it gets? Have you tried with smaller inputs? Your `while` condition is `while(sum(InfectedNodes) > 0)`, do you have reason to think that will ever *not* be the case for your inputs? Have you tried adjusting it to an "easier" condition to meet, to see if progress is made? Have you tried stepping through the loops one line at a time? Can you tell if the issue is in the `for(j in 1:nrow(Graph))` 2nd-level loop or the `for(j in 1:AmountNodes)` 2nd-level loop?...

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? Please specify the required packages. Also, I tried to run the example as is and the function terminates before your comment `#End Function_total`

Comment: Coming back to my previous comment: did you notice there are two `}` brackets when For-function j is supposed to end?

Comment: a) I want to simulate an infection starting from the first project (e.g. #1) and want to show, how many projects will be infected if the virus starts at project 1 for example. Starting, project 1 will be added to the InfectedNodes and then the algorithm needs to check the matrix, if row 1 is containing dependencies to different projects `Graph[k,j] > 0`. If this statement is true (meaning that there are dependencies to other projects), a random value is drawn between 0 and 1. Is this value < than the dependencies `RandomValue < (Graph[k,j])`, the other projects will be added to Infected Nodes.

Comment: b) More simple description: Take Project 1 as first infected project and add to InfectedNodes. After that, the algorithm needs to check if the project is infected in the adjacency matrix ("Graph"), and if so, all possible dependencies will be checked. The random value sample functions as a possible connection process, so it is possible that Project 1 connects to Project 2, but Project 1 does not connect to Project 3.

Comment: I think the problem is in: 
`while(sum(InfectedNodes) > 0){
      InfectedNodes_Reflection <- InfectedNodes
      for (j in 1:nrow(Graph)){
        if (Graph[j] == 1){
          for (k in 1:ncol(Graph)){
            if ((Graph[k,j] > 0 && (InfectedNodes[k,1]) == 0 && (ExcludedNodes[k,1]) == 0)){ 
              RandomValue <- runif(1, max=1, min=0) }
              if (RandomValue < (Graph[k,j])){
                InfectedNodes_Reflection[k] <- c(k) 
              } #End If-Function
            } #End If-Function
          } #End For-Function k
        } #End If-Function
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is located at the following lines:

```
...
while(sum(InfectedNodes) > 0){
  print(sum(InfectedNodes))
  InfectedNodes_Reflection <- InfectedNodes
...
```

`sum(InfectedNodes)` is constant and equals to `1`. So the loop is infinite.